# How to get an Object value in a single line expression in Javascript

Tags: javascript, react-native

So i have this below object and i want to return true or false based on the value.

```
obj =   
    {
        "closed": 
            {
                "CS1710897175876283": true
            },
        "unpaid": 
            {
                "CS1711279916237480": false, 
                "CS1711497275526501": true
            }
    }

console.log(obj['closed']) // {"CS1710897175876283": true}, this is fine
console.log(obj['closed']['CS1710897175876283']) // got error "TypeError: Cannot convert undefined value to object"

status={obj['unpaid']['CS1711279916237480'] ? "checked" :  "unchecked"} // got an error as well
```

How can get return true or false in just one line.

[image]

[image]

Comment: *"got error "TypeError: Cannot convert undefined value to object""* - [Are you sure about that](https://jsfiddle.net/0xy3wue8/)?

Comment: @David I just updated my question with a screenshot of the error produced and the line that produces the error

Comment: That’s a different error, and not one which is produced by the JavaScript code shown by itself.  You can test this by updating the question to a runnable code snippet.  The picture does however imply that you’re not just using plain JavaScript code by itself, but rather using React or even React Native.  But the code shown isn’t a React component.  Could you take some time to update the question and clarify the problem?

Comment: have you tried `console.log(obj.closed.CS1710897175876283)`?

Comment: Note that a `useEffect` may be executing before `orderCheckedList` has a value. Therefore `orderCheckedList.closed` may first be undefined and then later in time has a value. This is what you are seeing. It's not a javascript object problem. It is a React asynchronous behavior problem. Your're thinking in javascript. You need to think in React. To avoid the error do this: `console.log(orderCheckedList.closed?.CS1710897175876283)`. This syntax can't be used with the square bracket notation...

Comment: ... if you need to use the square bracket notation you need to do something like this: `console.log(orderCheckedList["closed"] && orderCheckedList["closed"]["CS1710897175876283"])` or `console.log(orderCheckedList["closed"] ? orderCheckedList["closed"]["CS1710897175876283"] : null)`

Answer (score 3):

Your code mostly works just fine. The last line of the code was not properly formed - I don't think you meant to put braces there.

```js
const obj =   
    {
        "closed": 
            {
                "CS1710897175876283": true
            },
        "unpaid": 
            {
                "CS1711279916237480": false, 
                "CS1711497275526501": true
            }
    }

console.log(obj['closed'])
console.log(obj['closed']['CS1710897175876283'])

const status = obj['unpaid']['CS1711279916237480'] ? "checked" :  "unchecked"

console.log(status)
```

Comment: thansk for your reply, i'm using in a react Native component so the need for the curly brace, but i have error running same code

Comment: the curly braces in react/reactnative are used to evaluate expressions (_in his case, the ternary operator_)

Comment: @MHDAlaaAlhaj: Isn’t that only true within JSX syntax?  The code shown in the question isn’t in any JSX, or even in a component at all.  It’s just plain JavaScript.  The OP really should clarify.  Otherwise those curly braces are nothing more than a typo in object literal syntax.

Comment: You are right and I understand that, but my thoughts are the OP didn't clarify (unintentionally) that he might be using `status` as `prop`, hence, you can see the attached screenshot stating that he got some errors with `<Card /><RCTViews> ...`